What did the Ancient Greeks think the stars were?
I've managed to find quite a bit of information around the internet about how the Greeks (5th BCE to 2nd CE, approximately) conceived of the motions of stars and planets (Almagesta, etc), but I'm struggling to find stuff about what they actually thought they were. The general consensus seems to have been that they were affixed to the firmament, but what exactly was affixed to the firmament? Jewels? Fires? Gateways into other realms?
Are there any foundational works on the beliefs that the Greeks held about stars and planets that I should investigate further to have a bigger picture?
(Part two of this question here)
(Some sources that I've already checked out here, though I will admit that I did not go through the entire article each time. I used some Ctrl+F to look for keywords in some so I may have missed details, and I have not explored the sources that these articles quote.)

Why do you think that the Ancient Greeks had an opinion on this topic? I suspect that they didn't know - they knew that life wasn't deterministic, that outcomes were influenced by things beyond their perception and knowledge and wondered if possibly the stars might be symbols of those influences.

@MCW I understand your point, but unlike quarks, stars are visible almost every night, and most people I know have wondered aloud as childred "what are the stars made out of?". I assume this isn't a new phenomenon, and given that constellation date back to before Ancient Greece, I also assume that there must have been some beliefs as to what they are or represent.

Good point - not the perfect example.  OTOH, everyone I know has a theory about how the economy works (most of them are unfathomably wrong), or how the opposite sex thinks, etc.  Even today, there are many observed, but untestable phenomenon. Pre-modern thinkers, who didn't have the scientific method are even less likely to achieve coherent opinions.  At least to me, the question seems founded on a presentist/modern premise that isn't really applicable to the ancient world.

Can you split your question into two? The composition of the stars and their influence are very different kinds of questions. I'll add some scholarship to my answer soon when I get a free moment at work.

@cmw done https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/76663

@MCW It's true, I am probably biased by the thinking patterns we tend to have in scientific communities nowadays (I work in public research). I don't assume that there was a general consensus that most philosophers agreed on, but I would guess that there were at least more popular "theories", perhaps dictated by the most popular philosopher in a given region for a givne time period. I'd be interested in more information on these ideas and who birthed them, if that was indeed the situation.

Water. (for at least one of them, anyway)

Traditionally, stars are associated with the divine. The origin of constellations, for example, are told with some frequency by poets, especially those who are relating myths. Theoi has a large collection of them.
While this probably endured at least in some form in traditional religion, various natural philosophers had other ideas about the composition of stars.
One of the more popular positions was that developed by Aristotle, who claimed that the stars are made up of "aether" (αἰθήρ), though that must be distinguished from Plato's usage: Quoting Wikipedia:

However, in his Book On the Heavens he introduced a new "first" element to the system of the classical elements of Ionian philosophy. He noted that the four terrestrial classical elements were subject to change and naturally moved linearly. The first element however, located in the celestial regions and heavenly bodies, moved circularly and had none of the qualities the terrestrial classical elements had. It was neither hot nor cold, neither wet nor dry. With this addition the system of elements was extended to five and later commentators started referring to the new first one as the fifth and also called it aether, a word that Aristotle had used in On the Heavens and the Meteorology.
Aether differed from the four terrestrial elements; it was incapable of motion of quality or motion of quantity. Aether was only capable of local motion. Aether naturally moved in circles, and had no contrary, or unnatural, motion. Aristotle also stated that celestial spheres made of aether held the stars and planets. The idea of aethereal spheres moving with natural circular motion led to Aristotle's explanation of the observed orbits of stars and planets in perfectly circular motion.

It's not just the heavens that are made of aether, but the stars they hold as well, as Aristotle claims in On the Heavens:

We have next to speak of the stars, as they are called, of their composition, shape, and movements. It would be most natural and consequent upon what has been said that each of the stars should be composed of that substance in which their path lies, since, as we said, there is an element whose natural movement is circular.

Interestingly enough, I think an earlier philosopher, Anaxagoras of Clazomenae, who preceded Aristotle's work by a century, was closer to the truth:

He was the first to give a correct explanation of eclipses, and was both famous and notorious for his scientific theories, including the claims that the sun is a mass of red-hot metal, that the moon is earthy, and that the stars are fiery stones.


I cannot remember what Aristotle exactly said, but the sentence you quoted and emphasised does not say that stars are made of aether. It says that the celestial sphere which holds the stars is made of aether.

@rexkogitans Added a direct quote from Aristotle. Thanks for pointing that out.

“In our world," said Eustace, "a star is a huge ball of flaming gas."
Even in your world, my son, that is not what a star is, but only what it is made of.”

@adam.baker "There was a boy called Eustace Clarence Scrubb, and he almost deserved it."

The Milesian philosophers certainly had some ideas.  I know they are a bit before your window of 5th BCE to 2nd CE, but the Pre-Socratics were quite interested in cosmology.

Thales of Miletus thought the stars were balls of dirt on
fire.

Anaximander supposed that the moon, sun and stars were not mere
objects in space but wheels of fire that surrounded the
Earth.

Anaximenes
thought stars were rarefied air.


