What influence did the Ancient Greeks believe the stars held upon everyday lives?
Spin-off of this question.
What sort of influence did the stars have on everyday life in the beliefs of the ancient Greeks (5th BCE to 2nd CE, approximately), and how is this influence excercised? Ptolemy's Tetrabiblos says "The stars in the feet of Gemini (Alhena and Tejat Posterior) have an influence similar to that of Mercury, and moderately to that of Venus.", but what influence did Mercury and Venus have?
Are there any foundational works on the beliefs that the Greeks held about stars and planets that I should investigate further to have a bigger picture?
(Some sources that I've already checked out here, though I will admit that I did not go through the entire article each time. I used some Ctrl+F to look for keywords in some so I may have missed details, and I have not explored the sources that these articles quote.)

the greeks did not beleive that the stars have any effect on us whatsoever. their worldview was finitist, they did not beleive in the actual infinite. anything that is too remote made them uncomfortable, which is why you never see the color blue on greek pottery

Quick answer:
from the end of book 1

Venus has the same powers and tempered nature as Jupiter, but acts in
the opposite way; for she warms moderately because of her nearness to
the sun, but chiefly humidifies, like the moon, because of the amount
of her own light and because she appropriates the exhalations from the
moist atmosphere surrounding the earth.
Jupiter has a temperate active force because his movement takes place
between the cooling influence of Saturn and the burning power of Mars.
He both heats and humidifies; and because his heating power is the
greater by reason of the underlying spheres, he produces fertilizing
winds.
Mercury in general is found at certain times alike to be drying and
absorptive of moisture, because he never is far removed in longitude
from the heat of the sun; and again humidifying, because he is next
above the sphere of the moon, which is closest to the earth; and to
change quickly from one to the other, inspired as it were by the speed
of his motion in the neighbourhood of the sun itself.

Long answer:
The vision of Ptolemy was modelled after Aristoteles in which the eart was at the center and the different cosmic object were positioned around on different spherical object, with the "fixed stars" at the end.
Ptolemy differentiates between two types of astronomical study: the first (astronomy proper) which discovers the astronomical cycles and movements; the second (astrology) which investigates the changes these movements bring about. The Tetrabiblos describe the latter.
The biggest influence was from (other than sun and moon) from planets in pairs::

Beneficent and Maleficent
Masculine and Feminine
Diurnal and Nocturnal​

Fixed stars where then classified based on the planets:

As it is next in order to recount the natures of the fixed stars with
reference to their special powers, we shall set forth their observed
characters in an exposition like that of the natures of the planets,
and in the first place those of the ones that occupy the figures in
the zodiac​ itself.

Was it considered useful?
Ptolemy uses 2 chapters (chapter 2 and chapter 3 of book 1) to discuss 2 arguments against astrology:

the complexity of the subject makes its claim of providing reliable foreknowledge unattainable
reliable foreknowledge—if it can be attained—would imply such fatalism as to make the subject's purpose useless (since if the future is predictable, anything which is destined to happen will happen whether predicted or not)

The conclusion (from Ptolemy) is:

it would not be fitting to dismiss all prognostication of this
character because it can sometimes be mistaken, for we do not
discredit the art of the pilot for its many errors;[...]

and

just as with prognostication, even if it be not entirely infallible,
at least its possibilities have appeared worthy of the highest regard,
so too in the case of a defensive practice, even though it does not
furnish a remedy for everything, its authority in some instances at
least, however few or unimportant, should be welcomed and prized and
regarded as profitable in no ordinary sense.

Is Tetrabyblos orginal content?
While wikipedia states

Much of the content of the Tetrabiblos was collected from earlier
sources; Ptolemy's achievement was to order his material in a
systematic way, showing how the subject could, in his view, be
rationalized. It is, indeed, presented as the second part of the study
of astronomy of which the Almagest was the first, concerned with the
influences of the celestial bodies in the sublunary sphere.

It is hard to find the specific references (no bibliography were included at the time, and we don't even know the exact original name of "Tetrabiblos").
A source states that

...Why did Ptolemy pay so much attention to the seemingly marginal
doctrine of the Terms? ...  The classical version of this system was
attributed to “the Egyptians,” that is: to Nechepso the King and
Petosiris his High Priest. Under these pseudonyms, which evoke the
idea of a far remote age, the core of Hellenistic astrology had in
truth been created and dispersed by unknown, Greek writing authors
in the second or first century BCE

(emphasis is mine)
We may conclude that we know that the content is not original because it has been found similar content on previous sources

Thank you for the detailed answer, and the links to external bibliography! Unless anyone gives another answer of comparable detila, I'll award you the bounty :) one small question: the vast majority of this is based on Ptolemy's work, is it known whether he work off of existing "knowledge", or did he "determine" these properties of the stars? I haven't had the chance to read throught the Tetrabiblos yet.

@Whitehot updated the answer with what I've found

Astrology was cultivated in ancient Babylon (in Persian Empire at that time), and came to Greece from there after Alexander's conquests, that is in 4-th century BC. There is no indication that believe in astrology was common among the Greeks before that. (People who lived in Hellenistic states after Alexander are usually not called "ancient Greeks").
After the conquest of Hellenistic states by the Romans, astrology flourished in Rome. (Ptolemy whom you mention lived in the Roman empire. He is sometimes called a Greek, but this only means that he wrote in Greek, which was the most common language in the late Roman empire.)
Astrology is not related to any system of religious beliefs. Its main premise is that the configuration of Sun, Moon and planets at a given moment somehow influences the fate of a person who
is born at this time. This configuration is called
a horoscope. Making a horoscope is a kind of "science" related to astronomy.
Moreover, depending on your horoscope, some daily configurations of planets can be lucky or unlucky for you during your life.
Christian rulers of the late empire banned astrology, together with all "pagan beliefs", but
astrology survived, and many people believe it even nowadays. Some mainstream journals still publish horoscopes.
By the way, in the word "disaster", "aster" means a star, and this word originally means "a bad (unfortunate) star alignment".
Ref. O. Neugebauer, Greek horoscopes

So what beliefs did they "inherit" from the Babylonians during that time? I'd guess not all of them, seeing as they didn't share a religion.

This had little to do with religion. This was a kind of "science", saying that a person's fate is influenced by the configuration of Sun, Moon and planets at the time of his/her birth. Many people of various religions still believe in this.

This doesn't appear to be responsive. Could you edit this to show how it answers the question and to provide citations to support the assertions?  The added content is even less responsive.  The question is about the ancient Greeks, not the Romans or  modern newspapers.

"Making a horoscope is a kind of science related to astronomy." This statement is ... unsupportable.  "Science is a strict systematic discipline that builds and organises knowledge in the form of testable hypotheses and predictions about the world"; astrology is not strict, and is not based on testable  hypothesis & predictions.

It was certainly considered as "science" by those who practiced it and believed it. And indeed, MAKING a horoscope (that is determining the planet configuration for a given time) was a kind of science. But BELIEVING that it determines peoples fates was not scientific. Some famous astronomers (for example Kepler) made a living by making horoscopes.

And Benjamin Rush believed that mercury was therapeutic.  But science tells us that the data (deaths due to mercury poisoning) is more important than belief.  I invite you to have the last word here because it is clear to me that we're not going to reach a consensus.

To make it clear: MAKING a horoscope was a science (it was based on astronomy). BELIEVING that it influences some person's fate was not.
